# Username field should come pre-filled with the username of the most recent user

Tags: codenameone

I would like my app to retrieve the most recent signed-in username on the login page. Instead of the username field coming when it's blank, I would like it to come when it is pre-filled with the username of the most recent user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this when initializing the text field:

```
myTextField.setText(Preferences.get("lastLogin", ""));
```

Then in the logged-in event processing code:

```
Preferences.put("lastLogin", myTextField.getText());
```